# How to set values of properties on scope by ng-click

Tags: angularjs

I have an icon bound to ng-click that binds to a $scope.remove function. In this function, i want to update some property values, mark the field dirty, and form post. Is there a way to do this in angular? Below is my remove function.

```
$scope.remove = function (index) {
    BootstrapDialog.show({
        title: 'WARNING',
        message: 'Are you sure you want to remove this delegation?',
        closable: false,
        buttons: [
        {
            label: 'OK',
            cssClass: 'btn-primary',
            action: function (dialogItself) {
                dialogItself.close();
                var row = JSON.stringify($scope.categoryFieldApprovers[index]);
                $scope.categoryFieldApprovers[index].StartDate = null;
                $scope.categoryFieldApprovers[index].EndDate = null;
                $scope.categoryFieldApprovers[index].ApproverTwoUserID = null; 
                $('form').submit(); 
            }
        }, {
            label: 'Cancel',
            cssClass: 'btn-primary',
            action: function (dialogItself) {
                dialogItself.close();
            }
        }],
        type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_WARNING,
        btnOKClass: 'btn-warning',
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

According the doc you can use

```
$setDirty();
```

Sets the form to a dirty state.

This method can be called to add the 'ng-dirty' class and set the form to a dirty state (ng-dirty class). This method will also propagate to parent forms.

```
$removeControl(control);
```

Deregister a control from the form.

Input elements using ngModelController do this automatically when they are destroyed.

Note that only the removed control's validation state ($errorsetc.) will be removed from the form. $dirty, $submitted states will not be changed, because the expected behavior can be different from case to case. For example, removing the only $dirty control from a form may or may not mean that the form is still $dirty.

```
$form.commit();
```

To submit the form

Comment: So does the assignment statements look right? Didn't mention that piece so just checking. Do i just add the line $SetDirty(); or does it attach to $scope.$SetDirty()?

Comment: I tried $setDirty(); but it comes back as undefined.

Comment: how did you use it ? it ''is `form.inputName.$setDirty()"` for a single element but `form.$setPristine();` should do the job

Comment: I tried both $scope.$setDirty() and just $setDirty(). My form is outside of my angular controller so i don't think it has visibility to it. <form><div controller></form>.